# how to select fields from a csv file to be imported into database?

Tags: php, mysql

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 
    'c:\sample data.csv' INTO TABLE
    companies(company_name,company_description) FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Comment: Could you please add more information? What are you trying to do? What is happening when this code is run, and what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'' at line 1

Comment: i want to insert a few selected fields from a csv file into my mysql database

Answer (score 0):

You can either omit `terminated by ...` statements or use them *before* mentioning the `column` names.

**Example 1**:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 
    'c:\sample data.csv' INTO TABLE
    companies(company_name,company_description);
```

**Example 2**:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 
    'c:\sample data.csv' INTO TABLE
    companies
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
    (company_name,company_description);
```

**Refer to Documentation**:

- **LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax**:

  - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html